# Looping the listing files in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, files

I've given the command:

```
ls -lrt
```

and the listed files and directories are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 abc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 cde
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 efg
-rwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2014 aaa.txt
```

Now I want to find whether the listed output files are directory or not by using for loop or while loop.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can already see which are directories - those are the ones that start with `d`.

Comment: yes, but i want to run each file in a loop and check whether it is a directory or not

Comment: The problem is you haven't explained what you want to do. "Check" is not an executable that you run. "Check" is something you can do with your eyes by looking to see if there is a `d`. Also, I presume your choice of `-rt` means the sort order is significant?

Comment: Would "_How to loop over the list of directories in the current directory sorted by modification time?_" be another way to ask what you really want?

Answer (score 2):

With `ls`, use the below command to list only directories.

```
ls -d -- */
```

To list regular files using ls itself (and assuming file names don't contain newline characters), you can use the below command.

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

To list only the regular files, with GNU and a few other find implementations, you can use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

(note that contrary to the previous one, it also include hidden files and the list is not sorted)

The standard equivalent would be:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f
```

Comment: Note that in the first one, that's not `ls` building the list of directories but the shell, `ls` ends up only displaying the arguments it receives. You might as well do `printf '%s\n' */`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Thanks for the edit. I was about to mention that the second command won't work on newlines of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have something like a "shell script template" for how to loop over directory contents and perform actions based on the file type, the following might give you a hint:

```bsh
for f in *
do
   if [[ -d "$f" ]]
   then
      ... your processing of directories here, reference them as "$f" ...
   fi
done
```

This would look over all entries in the current directory, check if they are directories, and performs any processing you like on them. Note that the syntax for the directory test is BASH-specific; for the general case, use `if [ -d "$f" ]`.

Another approach would restrict the list to only directory entries:

```bsh
for d in */
do
    ... whatever you need to do on directory "$d" ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a loop to find al the directories, you can use the `find` command instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

This will list all the directories in the current directory. If you want the `ls -l` output you can do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs ls -ld
```

If you really want to use a loop, you can use the following construct:

```
for file in $(ls)
do
  if [[ -d $file ]]
  then
    ls -ld $file
  fi
done
```

The `for` loop loops over all the entries returned by `ls`, then the `if` tests if the entry is a directory.

Comment: `for file in $(ls)` loops over the words that result from the outcome of the split+glob operator applied to the output of `ls`.  So it only loops over the list of files if none of the file names contain blank or wildcard characters. `for file in *` would be a lot better. Also note that `[[ -d $file ]]` also returns true for symlinks to directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you're given only the `ls -ltr` output, then continue reading this post.
Otherwise have a look at what other posters, like [Ramesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137024/65525) or [mtak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137025/65525), suggested.

The first letter of each line in your output tells you if it's a directory or not.

So my naive solution would be:

```
while read line; do
  [ "${line:0:1}" == "d" ] && echo "$line" | awk '{print $NF}' # it is a directory, echo the directory name
done < outputfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

list directory names

```
compgen -d
```

Not starting from a point

```
compgen -d -X '.*' | xargs ls -dlrt
```

Comment: (1) Note that, like `[ -d … ]`, this includes symbolic links to directories.  (2) Why does your second command include `| xargs ls -dlrt`?

Comment: @Scott, thanks for symbolic links. Second command included for extended output and sorting.